# Which background process used for continous fetching of data from Twitter through ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, background-process, twitter-gem

My application need continous fetching of data from Twitter. I used twitter gem to access Twitter API. Have used #rufus-scheduler to hit the Twitter API after every half an hour, but it is not working, as some time it is blocked by the Twitter API for increasing limit.

Answer (score 1):

I have already answered to a similar question here [Background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705526/rails-3-1-rake-datespecific-tasks-without-queues/8863397#8863397)

Basically, if you want to periodically fetch something on the Twitter API, you can use a cron job, but if you want to do it in real time, consider using a background job.

**Example**

```
while true
  if thereIsSomethingToDo
     # Do something here...
  else
     sleep 60 # Could be + or -
  end 
end
```

There is different ways to manage background jobs. Here is one:

1. Wrap your code in a **rake task**
2. Run this rake task from a process monitor like **[Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/)** or **[God](http://godrb.com/)**